# ¿Cómo puedo unir dos arreglos en otro arreglo en java?

Tags: java, array

Soy nueva programando. Hice este ejercicio hasta una cierta parte. ¿Cómo puedo unir dos arreglos en otro arreglo sin repetir sus elementos?
El ejercicio es el siguiente:

/*
Realizar un programa que permita generar números comprendidos entre 100 y 999
y cargar en vectores A y B. Crear un vector C,
que sea el resultado de la unión de los vectores A y B (el vector C no debe
tener elementos repetidos). Imprimir los vectores A, B y C.
*/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int elementos1=0, elementos2=0;
    int min = 100;
    int max = 999;
    
    elementos1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de elementos del primer vector:"));
    int vA [] = new int [elementos1];
    
    for (int x=0;x<vA.length;x++){
        vA[x] = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
    }
    
   elementos2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de elementos del segundo vector:"));
   int vB [] = new int [elementos2];
   
   for (int x=0;x<vB.length;x++){
       vB[x] = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
   }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "el vector C no debe tener elementos repetidos" donde haces esto?

Comment: Tendrías que recorrer ambos arreglos, que se vayan comparando para que no haya repetidos, si no es repetido entonces lo insertas en un nuevo arreglo, debido a que es dinámico el tamaño de los arreglos tienes que terminar de comparar los elementos hasta que termine el arreglo más grande

Comment: Puedes hacer un ArrayList y agregar todos los elementos con [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-javfirst.lang.Object-int-javfirst.lang.Object-int-int-)  Puedes hacer uso de este método para copiar elementos de las arrays dadas en una arrays vacía recién asignada.

```
int[] vC = new int[vA.length + vB.length];
System.arraycopy(vA, 0, vC, 0, vA.length);
System.arraycopy(vB, 0, vC, vA.length, vB.length);
```

o Usando java 8+

puedes usar el método InStream.concat()

```
int[] vC= IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(vA), Arrays.stream(vB))
                    .toArray()
```